# Making Player dash towards Cursor with a set length

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add dashing to the player in a Diablo-esque game I'm working on, and it "works" where you can dash towards your cursor.

```
if (isDashing)
{
      Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
      RaycastHit hit;

      if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100, movementMask))
      {
           motor.MoveToPoint(hit.point);
           motor.speed = 150;
      }
 }
```

I get the mouse position, then move to that position with enormous velocity. MoveToPoint() function uses NavMeshAgent's SetDestination(point) function and this again "works" but the problem is naturally there isn't a limit to how far you can dash. You can have the mouse way over at the end of the screen and the character will still dash there.

I figured I should be using a Vector3 to define the limits of the dash, but I can't quite nail it down. I get the direction below and then apply the magnitude, but it does not work how I imagined it would.

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100, movementMask))
{
      float mag = (hit.point - transform.position).magnitude;
      if (mag < dashLength)
      {
          Vector3 dir = (hit.point - transform.position).normalized;
          Vector3 newVector = dir * (dashLength - mag);
          motor.MoveToPoint(newVector);
      }
      else
          motor.MoveToPoint(hit.point);
      motor.agent.speed = 150;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that you are treating a movement vector like a position. You want to start a the current `transform.position` and **ADD** the movement vector you calculated.

Further instead of extracting and checking the magnitude you can simply use [`Vector3.ClampMagnitude`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ClampMagnitude.html) to keep the direction but make sure that the magnitude is not greater than your `dashLength` like e.g.

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100, movementMask))
{
    // Calculate the difference only once
    var movement = hit.point - transform.position;
    // Make sure that delta has a maximum magnitude of dashLength
    movement = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(delta, dashLength);
   
    // MoveToPoint expects a position not only the movement vector
    // so you start at your current position and add the movement
    var newPosition = transform.position + movement;

    motor.MoveToPoint(newPosition);
    motor.agent.speed = 150;
}
```